# Rails 3 Routes - routing a parameter different to :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have problems getting clear about the new routing system of Rails 3+.

I want to match "/:name" to :controller => :profiles, :action => :show, :name => name

How do I realize this?

I tried with `match "/:name" => "profiles#show"` but this just uses the :name as :id...

Yours Joern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `match "/:name" => "profiles#show"` this is going to trigger the `show` action on the `profiles` controller.  Inside that controller instance you can access the matched URL from `params[:name]`

I assume you are trying to get a Model record by name instead of id, thus you must modify your `show` action.  For instance,

```
def show
  @profile = Profile.find_by_name(params[:name])
end
```

Comment: that's what I expected and did. :/ so my solution seems to be right, the error must be somewhere else